# Automatically delete database row when condition is met (SQL)

Tags: php, sql

I am needing to delete rows in a table automatically when a specific condition is met. There are other questions similar, but I believe their answers do not apply or are out of date.

Anyhoo-

In my database, I have a table which tracks player stats, each player has a "game" based contract. When they sign, they choose the amount of games they'd like to play under the contract, so let's say 20. After each game, it is ticked down, until it reaches zero. HERE, is where I'd like for the row to be removed. when the contract expires.

As far as I am aware, I have two options.

1) Sched a cron to run every day  to remove them.
2) check the games_left col after every single alteration.

Of course, with 1), it's not instant, which isn't ideal. With 2), it seems... like there MUST be another more eloquent way to perform this task.

We're using MariaDB & SQL.

Could anyone help? :)

Comment: why don't you check it in your code? Like before updating the table, you check if there are games left, and if not you remove the line instead of updating it.

Comment: Yes, check the row whenever you make a change to games_left and delete it when the value goes to 0. You may enjoy [this amusing article](https://hackernoon.com/why-senior-devs-write-dumb-code-and-how-to-spot-a-junior-from-a-mile-away-27fa263b101a).

Comment: @LioraHaydont We're unable to do that. Due to the nature of our system, their statistics must first be updated. Removing after updating means we can do it instantly. If they're left on the "roster" without a contract, it will cause internal, and communal issues :/

Comment: @BobRodes Cheers Bob! Thank you for that. And yes, that article certainly is amusing. Dumb code is great, but there's sometimes this feeling of "I don't think I need to write dumb code for this", if that makes sense? Hard to find the balance

Comment: You're in effect saying that there must be something more elegant than evaluating a condition each time that you alter the data, because the condition doesn't happen very often. If you update something conditionally, then you have to check the condition every time you update. A more obvious example of the principle: there isn't a more elegant way, when requesting a user to provide a file name, to handle a file not found error by checking every time to see whether the file is there, even though it usually is.

Comment: Yes, it is hard. My first application, I didn't want to leave extra files on the disk. So I wrote a database application that dynamically wrote a report specification every time a report was requested. Meaning, instead of just changing the report spec file every time a change was needed, I had to go digging through the code and changing it. Not a good solution in terms of maintenance overhead! Not to mention violating every principle of loose coupling that's ever been defined. :)

Comment: After having you put the principle in another example, I feel incredibly stupid! LOL. You're totally right. The article in itself gives a huge insight into "dumb code". I'd call myself relatively new in backend scripting, so that has certainly altered my mindset somewhat. Thank you very much for passing on some wisdom, haha!

Comment: @Joe You're very welcome. Glad I could help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a view so the rows are invisible:

```
create view v_playerstats as
    select ps.*
    from playerstats ps
    where  ps.numgames > 0;
```

Have all your access to the data be through this view.  You can even arrange it so users have access to the view but not the underlying table.

Then, you can remove the rows at your leisure.

The alternative is to create an `update` trigger -- presumably you are using `update` to decrement the value.  The trigger can delete the row (or move it to another table) when the value goes to 0.

I actually prefer the first method.  If you have peak periods on your database, it allows you to move the `delete` operations to a quieter time.

Comment: I'd use the view method , but unfortunately the data will need to  be removed. If they aren't in the table, they're a free agent, meaning they can sign for others. I'll use the trigger though! Thank you.